# excel vba: get cell before selection

Tags: excel, get, selection, cell

I have the following problem in an Excel table. I want to have the same formatting in a line depending on the first cell. Here is what I came up with so far:

```
Sub LineFormatSynch()

  FSize = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Font.Size
  FName = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Font.Name
  FColor = Selection.Offset(0, -1).Font.Color
  FHAlign = Selection.Offset(0, -1).HorizontalAlignment
  FVAlign = Selection.Offset(0, -1).VerticalAlignment

  For Each c In Range("E196:BR196")

    c.Font.Size = FSize
    c.Font.Name = FName
    c.Font.Color = FColor
    c.HorizontalAlignment = FHAlign
    c.VerticalAlignment = FVAlign

  Next

End Sub
```

But it is not flexible enough. Basically I want to select a line and click execute macro and the selected cells should be formatted in the manner of the first cell. But I cannot figure out how to extract the address for the first cell from my selection. I have the row number in my selection.address like "$E$197:$BR$197". The cell I want the formatting from is always in column "D". How can I extract "197" from my selection.address? With a regular expression or is there a better way?

best, US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler solution I think but thx. Here it is:

```
Sub LineFormatSynch()

  Dim RowNumber As Integer

  RowNumber = Selection.Row
  OriginAddress = "D" & CStr(RowNumber)

  FSize = Range(OriginAddress).Font.Size
  FName = Range(OriginAddress).Font.Name
  FColor = Range(OriginAddress).Font.Color
  FHAlign = Range(OriginAddress).HorizontalAlignment
  FVAlign = Range(OriginAddress).VerticalAlignment

  For Each c In Selection

    c.Font.Size = FSize
    c.Font.Name = FName
    c.Font.Color = FColor
    c.HorizontalAlignment = FHAlign
    c.VerticalAlignment = FVAlign

  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know. But I voted you back up given you found your own solution and were kind enough to post it back to the forum

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a way to reference a table

```
Sub LineFormatSynch()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim rw As Range

    Set cl = ActiveCell
    Set lst = cl.ListObject
    If Not lst Is Nothing Then ' in case ActiveCell is not in a table
        Set rw = lst.DataBodyRange.Rows(cl.Row - lst.DataBodyRange.Row + 1)

        With rw
            .Font.Size = cl.Font.Size
            .Font.Name = cl.Font.Name
            .Font.Color = cl.Font.Color
            .HorizontalAlignment = cl.HorizontalAlignment
            .VerticalAlignment = cl.VerticalAlignment
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

To use, select the cell you want to use as the template format for a row, then run the macro.  It will:

1. Detect if the active cell is in a table.
2. Set a reference to the row the selected cell is in
3. Apply the format of the selcted cell to all cells in the same row in the table

`Set lst = cl.ListObject` provides a reference to the Table
If `cl` is not in a table, `lst` will be set to `Nothing`
`lst.DataBodyRange` provides a reference to the table data (excludes the header row)
`Set rw = ...` sets a reference to the table row containing the active cell
The five lines inside the `With` clause copy the properties from `cl` to all cells in `rw`

BTW this is tested on Excel 2010, if your version is different there may be some differences, let me know

**Edit 2:**

For a generic range of a sheet that just *looks* like a table, consider:

```
Sub LineFormatSynch()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim lst As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Set cl = ActiveCell
    Set lst = cl.CurrentRegion
    If Not lst Is Nothing Then
        Set rw = lst.Rows(cl.Row - lst.Row + 1)

        With rw
            .Font.Size = cl.Font.Size
            .Font.Name = cl.Font.Name
            .Font.Color = cl.Font.Color

            .HorizontalAlignment = cl.HorizontalAlignment
            .VerticalAlignment = cl.VerticalAlignment
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The current region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns

Comment: The code above presumes that by *"Excel table"* you meant a defined  Excel Table [see here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/use-excel-tables-to-manage-information-RZ102252956.aspx?section=2). If you meant that you have a table-like layout then the code won't make any changes

Comment: Yes. It was a misunderstanding. Sorry about that. I meant an Excel sheet in a file.